# What is the verb for pushing, shoving plants so as to create a path

Tags: word-request

By shoving and pushing I don't mean shove it just to have it bounce back, but cracking and cutting down plants. I am not sure how to say this, let me just give you and example:

> The airplane flew through the jungle and ___ the plants and foliage
>   with its sonic boom, forming a permanent path through the jungle.

People also do this with a machete, like in the following example:

> The guide ___ the thick foliage with a machete allowing the tourists
>   to walk with more ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One "hacks" through the jungle, using a machete. This gives an impression of difficult movement, as is common in dense forests.

This works well for your second example.  The first example seems odd to me, as a sonic boom is loud but doesn't cut down plants.  Even if the plane flew low over the jungle it wouldn't create a path.  If the plane actually crashed into the jungle it might leave a "trail of destruction". The situation is peculiar, but perhaps you could use "hacked" here too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word **scythe**. The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scythe) has:

> **scythe**
>   VERB [with object]
>
> **1** Cut with a scythe.
>
> *the first job was to scythe paths through the nettles*

So your sentences could be

> The airplane flew through the jungle and **scythed** the plants and foliage with its sonic boom, forming a permanent path through the jungle.
>
> The guide **scythed** the thick foliage with a machete allowing the tourists to walk with more ease.

The **scythe** is a tool used in UK to do the job, we don't use the machete.